# Pulling data from employer table if employer is mapped with multiple user in user table

Tags: mysql, sql

So i have 2 tables e_employer and e_user in e_user table using e_employer id as foreign key
and we can have multiple user with 1 employer_id

so I want to pull all the employer with only 1 user

**e_employer**

```
employer_id int(11)
employername varchar(100)
```

**e_user**

```
user_id int(11)
username varchar(100)
employer_id int(11)
```

I am not able to think how can I pull it, please suggest to me what I should try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT e.employer_id
FROM e_employer e
WHERE (SELECT count(user_id) FROM e_user u WHERE u.employer_id = e.employer_id) = 1
```